# Cannot SSH to Azure Linux VM from terminal

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, azure

`ssh azureuser@xxx.cloudapp.net : 22`

when I connect and enter the password I created, then it just goes back to the local prompt and does not actually show the remote prompt.

I'm thinking I need to go about creating the ssh key instead of a user/password?

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-ssh-key/

Comment: you don't have to specify port 22 - port 22 is default for ssh

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by uploading a certificate when I created the VM and then using the private key locally from SSH command.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-ssh-key/

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout azure.key -out azure.pem`

`chmod 600 azure.key`

`ssh -i azure.key user@xxx.cloudapp.net -p 22`

Comment: just to clarify. you have 2 options when creating a linux vm. you can ssh to it using certificates or only password based. By default certificate is used. You have to manually switch to password based during the creation process.